# ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 Self-Referencing One-to-Many Relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model `Package` which I would like to add a collection property `Dependencies` on, where a dependency is simply another package (think NuGet):

```
public class Package
{
    public Package()
    {
        Version = "0.0.0";
    }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Description cannot be longer than 500 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Version is in an invalid format (Major.Minor.Build).")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    [DisplayName("Release Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Published?")]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public string ReleaseNotesURL { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Platform")]
    public int? PlatformID { get; set; }

    public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Package> Dependencies { get; set; } // <== THIS IS THE NEW PROPERTY
}
```

I'm using automatic migrations, so `Add-Migration AddDependendies` generates the following class:

```
public partial class AddDependencies : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Packages", "Package_ID", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Packages", "Package_ID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Packages", "Package_ID", "dbo.Packages", "ID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Packages", "Package_ID", "dbo.Packages");
        DropIndex("dbo.Packages", new[] { "Package_ID" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Packages", "Package_ID");
    }
}
```

I read this schema change as a reference to a single existing package. To create multiple package references will require additional rows, containing all duplicate data (except for `Package_ID`). This doesn't seem quite right to me, or perhaps it's just a limitation of a relational database.

Can't we just store an array of PackageIDs in a column, or use some other mechanism that doesn't generate duplicate data?

Comment: You will no need top create an additional entity but you will have to create a custom mapping for this scenario.

Comment: @E-Bat could you elaborate please?

Comment: Ok, I posted my proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

The schema you have does not correctly represent the problem you are trying to solve. Since multiple packages could depend on the same package (i.e. everything depends on EF) you need to create a many to many relationship. The m:m support in EF is somewhat limited so the easiest would be to create a new entity (=table) for dependencies: you need two fields (=columns) - one for the parent and one for the child of the dependency.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give that a try and report back :)

Answer (score 1):

EF cant resolve the mapping for you in this case, you will need a custom mapping similar to the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Dependencies)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("Package_ID");
                m.MapRightKey("ID");
                m.ToTable("PackageDependency");
            });
}
```

This will indicate EF to generate DDL code to create an union table to store all possible relation/dependencies between packages.

Comment: How would I modify my migration to support this?

Comment: If you have applied your migration to the db you will need to rollback and create a new migration with this mapping.

Comment: I added this method to my `DbContext` class, but I get the error "The name 'Dependencies' does not exist in the current context". Do I need to add a `DbSet<Package> Dependencies` to model this?

Comment: Oh no sorry, it should be  p.Dependencies. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ah ok! I'm also adding this to my migration: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8c0762a0e23a8231d87  does this look correct?

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the composite PK "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'PackageDependency'. Only one identity column per table is allowed."

Comment: That is because in your migration you are specifing both fields as identity, you dont need identity for this table. See my edit.

Comment: I think the migration conflicts with the `m.ToTable("PackageDependency")` in `OnModelCreating()`. I get the error 'There is already an object named 'PackageDependency' in the database.' when running `Update-Database`. I was certain to reverse the previous migration beforehand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76712/discussion-between-mark-richman-and-e-bat).